# I am unable to resolve syntax error on pip install

Tags: python, syntax

New to python. Cannot find error in archives. Here is my environment and error I am receiving in doing first install:

```
Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
pip install --user send2trash==1.5.0
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this `pip install` command from inside a Python interpreter? That's not going to work – it's a shell command.

Comment: Execute it on a Python terminal, not interpreter.

Comment: OK, I understand about not using an interpreter to run the command - pip install. Thanks for that. However, a 'Python Terminal' - the internet is of minimal help with that term. So, I have to run this command in a Python environment, but not in the interpreter. Where is that environment? It definitely is not on a google search screen.